# How to write Python and shell console outputs to a file in an order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, logging

I am running an impdp statement form inside a Python File and I want to write the print statements in Python script in the logfile, which is being created in 'abccmd' using '>>' append symbol.

Two issues to be resolved:

1. The print commands are overwriting the logs generated using impdp commands
2. I want the logs to be in order in which they come in script (All the print commands are coming at top of the log file. Even the commands that are after the impdp statement in the function being called)

Also, I am using dynamic naming system for logfiles that are created.

```
def import_command_run(DP_WORKLOAD, dp_workload_cmd, imp_loop, vardate):
        abccmd = 'impdp admin/DP_PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD@DP_PDB_FULL_NAME SCHEMAS=ABC >>' + logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '_' + DP_WORKLOAD + '_' + str(vardate) + '.log 2>&1'
        defcmd = 'impdp admin/DP_PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD@DP_PDB_FULL_NAME SCHEMAS=DEF >>' + logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '_' + DP_WORKLOAD + '_' + str(vardate) + '.log 2>&1'

    # any of the above commands
    run_imp_cmd(eval(abccmd))

def run_imp_cmd(cmd):
    output = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout,stderr = output.communicate()
    return stdout
```

All the Print commands used in imp_workload() and the main() methods should come in exact order in the log file.

```
def imp_workload(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, vardate):
        imp_loop = 1
        while DP_DURATION_SECONDS > 0:
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("                                               PDB " + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] +  " for Workload " + DP_WORKLOAD + ": Import number " + str(imp_loop) + " Starts")
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

            duration = 0
            print("\nImport is running for Time loop : " + str(imp_loop))
            startImport = datetime.now()
            start = time.time()
            print("Start Time for the Import is    : " + startImport.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
       
            # Calling the above function here
            import_command_run(DP_WORKLOAD, dp_workload_cmd, imp_loop, vardate)
            time.sleep(60)

            stop = time.time()
            endImport = datetime.now()
            print("Stop Time for the Import is     : " + endImport.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            duration = stop - start

            print("\nTotal Time elapsed for Data Pump Import Time loop " + str(imp_loop) + ": " + str(int(duration/3600)) + " hours " + str(int(((duration/60)%60))) + " minutes " + str(int((duration % 60))) + " seconds\n")

            DP_DURATION_SECONDS = DP_DURATION_SECONDS - duration

            if DP_DURATION_SECONDS>0:
                print("\nData Pump Import will again run for: " + str(int(DP_DURATION_SECONDS)) + " seconds\n")
            else:
                print("\nDATA Pump Import has ended for the workload: " + DP_WORKLOAD + "\n")

            imp_loop = imp_loop + 1
```

I am trying to use sys.stdout as you can see. But it is overwriting the logfile created by the impdp statement.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        vardate = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%I_%M_%S_%p")

        # Running loop through each workload mentioned in the config file
        for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))):
                print("\n==========================================================================================================================================")
                print("\n                                                    Data Pump Workload has Started                                                        \n")
                print("==========================================================================================================================================")

                # Conversion of time form minutes to seconds
                DP_DURATION_SECONDS = int(DP_DURATION) * 60

                now = datetime.now()
                print("Current Date and Time: " + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

                print("\nData Pump Import will run for " + DP_DURATION  + " minutes\n")

                for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
                        sys.stdout = open(logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '_' + DP_WORKLOAD  +  '_' + str(vardate) + '.log', 'w')
                        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, vardate, ))
                        p1.start()
                        sys.stdout.close()
```

Please suggest a way to log them in a proper way.

Comment: It's simple. Don't use `print()` for logging. Use the logger for logging.

Comment: @Tomalak but how will I add statements I want using the logger? And also, how to merge the import logs generated using the impdp statement?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example

Comment: Regarding `impdp` - it's a separate process (several, actually, since you're using multiprocessing) - you can't just merge those files with the logs your Python process generates. But you could play with [`impdp`'s logging configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-363F6A16-596B-4110-B5A7-9F2691BE9604.htm#SUTIL918) to set-up sequential logfile names with Python before you start each import process. Maybe that's enough? If you really must *merge* them with Python's logs, you will have to write code that reads in all those files and does it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder this may be the result you want, anyway, you can try this one:

```
python -m abc.py > d:\output.txt
```

It makes output.txt in d: and it will record all the print results in the order they are called.

Comment: I am using dynamic naming for log file names actually.